# Neo4j apoc functions doesn't exist

Tags: plugins, neo4j

I have Neo4j Community version installed and I copied the apoc file in the plugins folder in my database. I configured the config file as well to allow all the apoc functions to work.

still RETURN apoc.version() or call apoc.help() functions doesn't exist but some of the apoc funcitons like apoc.load.json et cetera exist. What am i doing wrong??

```
dbms.security.allow_csv_import_from_file_urls=true

apoc.export.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.enabled=true
apoc.import.file.use_neo4j_config=true
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.white_list=apoc.load.*

dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.cypher.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.meta.*
NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*


# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.auth_enabled=true
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.meta.*
NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\*

# With default configuration Neo4j only accepts local connections.
# To accept non-local connections, uncomment this line:
#dbms.connectors.default_listen_address=0.0.0.0

name    signature   description
"apoc.coll.partition"   "apoc.coll.partition(values :: LIST? OF ANY?, batchSize :: INTEGER?) :: (value :: LIST? OF ANY?)"   "apoc.coll.partition(list,batchSize)"
"apoc.coll.split"   "apoc.coll.split(values :: LIST? OF ANY?, value :: ANY?) :: (value :: LIST? OF ANY?)"   "apoc.coll.split(list,value) | splits collection on given values rows of lists, value itself will not be part of resulting lists"
"apoc.coll.zipToRows"   "apoc.coll.zipToRows(list1 :: LIST? OF ANY?, list2 :: LIST? OF ANY?) :: (value :: LIST? OF ANY?)"   "apoc.coll.zipToRows(list1,list2) - creates pairs like zip but emits one row per pair"
"apoc.load.csv" "apoc.load.csv(url :: STRING?, config :: MAP?) :: (lineNo :: INTEGER?, list :: LIST? OF ANY?, map :: MAP?)" "apoc.load.csv('url',{config}) YIELD lineNo, list, map - load CSV fom URL as stream of values,\n config contains any of: {skip:1,limit:5,header:false,sep:'TAB',ignore:['tmp'],arraySep:';',mapping:{years:{type:'int',arraySep:'-',array:false,name:'age',ignore:false}}"
"apoc.load.driver"  "apoc.load.driver(driverClass :: STRING?) :: VOID"  "apoc.load.driver('org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver') register JDBC driver of source database"
"apoc.load.jdbc"    "apoc.load.jdbc(jdbc :: STRING?, tableOrSql :: STRING?, params = [] :: LIST? OF ANY?) :: (row :: MAP?)" "apoc.load.jdbc('key or url','table or statement') YIELD row - load from relational database, from a full table or a sql statement"
"apoc.load.jdbcParams"  "apoc.load.jdbcParams(jdbc :: STRING?, sql :: STRING?, params :: LIST? OF ANY?) :: (row :: MAP?)"   "deprecated - please use: apoc.load.jdbc('key or url','statement',[params]) YIELD row - load from relational database, from a sql statement with parameters"
"apoc.load.jdbcUpdate"  "apoc.load.jdbcUpdate(jdbc :: STRING?, query :: STRING?, params = [] :: LIST? OF ANY?) :: (row :: MAP?)"    "apoc.load.jdbcUpdate('key or url','statement',[params]) YIELD row - update relational database, from a SQL statement with optional parameters"
"apoc.load.json"    "apoc.load.json(url :: STRING?, path = :: STRING?, config = {} :: MAP?) :: (value :: MAP?)" "apoc.load.json('url',path, config) YIELD value - import JSON as stream of values if the JSON was an array or a single value if it was a map"
"apoc.load.jsonArray"   "apoc.load.jsonArray(url :: STRING?, path = :: STRING?) :: (value :: ANY?)" "apoc.load.jsonArray('url') YIELD value - load array from JSON URL (e.g. web-api) to import JSON as stream of values"
"apoc.load.jsonParams"  "apoc.load.jsonParams(url :: STRING?, headers :: MAP?, payload :: STRING?, path = :: STRING?, config = {} :: MAP?) :: (value :: MAP?)"  "apoc.load.jsonParams('url',{header:value},payload, config) YIELD value - load from JSON URL (e.g. web-api) while sending headers / payload to import JSON as stream of values if the JSON was an array or a single value if it was a map"
"apoc.load.ldap"    "apoc.load.ldap(connection :: ANY?, search :: MAP?) :: (entry :: MAP?)" "apoc.load.ldap(\"key\" or {connectionMap},{searchMap}) Load entries from an ldap source (yield entry)"
"apoc.load.xml" "apoc.load.xml(url :: STRING?, path = / :: STRING?, config = {} :: MAP?, simple = false :: BOOLEAN?) :: (value :: MAP?)"    "apoc.load.xml('http://example.com/test.xml', 'xPath',config, false) YIELD value as doc CREATE (p:Person) SET p.name = doc.name load from XML URL (e.g. web-api) to import XML as single nested map with attributes and _type, _text and _childrenx fields."
"apoc.load.xmlSimple"   "apoc.load.xmlSimple(url :: STRING?) :: (value :: MAP?)"    "apoc.load.xmlSimple('http://example.com/test.xml') YIELD value as doc CREATE (p:Person) SET p.name = doc.name load from XML URL (e.g. web-api) to import XML as single nested map with attributes and _type, _text and _children fields. This method does intentionally not work with XML mixed content."
```

Comment: Have you restarted Neo4 service after changing `neo4j.conf` file?

Comment: yes multiple times i have restarted my computer.

Answer (score 3):

Ah found it.

when I copied the jar file I removed all the procedures below

```
# Require (or disable the requirement of) auth to access Neo4j
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.*
dbms.security.procedures.whitelist=apoc.coll.*,apoc.load.*
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.trigger.*,apoc.meta.*
NEO4J_dbms_security_procedures_unrestricted=apoc.\\\*
```

and pasted only this

```
dbms.security.procedures.unrestricted=apoc.*
```

Answer (score 0):

```
docker run \
    -p 7474:7474 -p 7687:7687 \
    -v $PWD/data:/data -v $PWD/plugins:/plugins \
    --name neo4j-apoc \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_export_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_enabled=true \
    -e NEO4J_apoc_import_file_use__neo4j__config=true \
    -e NEO4JLABS_PLUGINS=\[\"apoc\"\] \
    neo4j:4.0
```